# Count the number of occurrences of the event with the last 30 days

Tags: r, count, find-occurrences

I would like to count the number of times the person was contacted within the last 30 days in R. Here is the data:

```
> df1
   ID       Date     Time Call_Status           Date_Time     x
7   1 2017-08-02  1:00:01     Contact 2017-08-02 01:00:01  TRUE
6   1 2017-09-01  1:00:00  No Contact 2017-09-01 01:00:00 FALSE
3   1 2017-09-02  2:00:00     Contact 2017-09-02 02:00:00  TRUE
2   1 2017-10-01  9:00:00     Contact 2017-10-01 09:00:00  TRUE
1   1 2017-10-01 13:00:00     Contact 2017-10-01 13:00:00  TRUE
5   2 2017-08-02  5:00:00     Contact 2017-08-02 05:00:00  TRUE
4   2 2017-09-01  3:00:00  No Contact 2017-09-01 03:00:00 FALSE
8   2 2017-11-01  2:00:00     Contact 2017-11-01 02:00:00  TRUE
10  3 2017-03-06 12:31:03  No Contact 2017-03-06 12:31:03 FALSE
11  3 2017-04-06 19:55:02     Contact 2017-04-06 19:55:02  TRUE
9   3 2017-05-02 18:00:05     Contact 2017-05-02 18:00:05  TRUE
```

I care about the time (hours, minutes, seconds), that is, if the customer was contacted an hour ago (even if this happened on the same day), I would like to count it as an occurrence. Ideally I want to get the following table

```
 id     x          d        t                  dt dminus30 
5   1  TRUE 2017-10-01 13:00:00 2017-10-01 13:00:00        2        
4   1  TRUE 2017-10-01  9:00:00 2017-10-01 09:00:00        1        
3   1  TRUE 2017-09-02  2:00:00 2017-09-02 02:00:00        0        
2   1 FALSE 2017-09-01  1:00:00 2017-09-01 01:00:00        1        
1   1  TRUE 2017-08-02  1:00:01 2017-08-02 01:00:01        0        
8   2  TRUE 2017-11-01  2:00:00 2017-11-01 02:00:00        0        
7   2 FALSE 2017-09-01  3:00:00 2017-09-01 03:00:00        1        
6   2  TRUE 2017-08-02  5:00:00 2017-08-02 05:00:00        0        
11  3  TRUE 2017-05-02 18:00:05 2017-05-02 18:00:05        1        
10  3  TRUE 2017-04-06 19:55:02 2017-04-06 19:55:02        0        
9   3 FALSE 2017-03-06 12:31:03 2017-03-06 12:31:03        0
```

The code I wrote does not work precisely as it does not count hours, minutes and seconds. Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

```
orderDT = with(df1,data.table(id = ID, x = x, d = Date, t = Time, dt = Date_Time))

vec = list(minus30 = 30L, minus60 = 60L)
vec

# If we don't count any calls on the same day

orderDT[,c("dminus30", "dminus60"):=.(
  orderDT[x][orderDT[,.(id,d_minus30 = d-vec$minus30, d_yest = d - 1L)], on=.
             (id, d >= d_minus30, d <= d_yest), .N, by = .EACHI] $N

  ,

  orderDT[x][orderDT[,.(id,d_minus60 = d-vec$minus60, d_yest = d - 1L)], on=.
                        (id, d >= d_minus60, d <= d_yest), .N, by = .EACHI] $N
)]


new <- as.data.frame(orderDT)

sorted_new <-new[with(new,order(new$id, desc(new$dt))),]
```

Comment: Edit your post and add the language you're using to the tags section.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I edited it.

Comment: You've still not specified what language you're using.

Comment: @hnefatl . I am using _R_ language